# Google calendar API issue - daylight saving

Tags: asp.net-web-api, calendar, timezone, save, dst

I made an application using the Google calendar API, to evaluate events and finally also adds an event to a calendar. Now we come close to the switch to daylight saving time I have the problem: the API is shifting time for one hour.
Example:

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
   'summary' => 'title',
   'description' => 'description',
   'start' => array(
       'dateTime' => '2018-04-05T12:00:00+1:00',
       'timeZone' => 'Europe/Amsterdam',
   ),
   'end' => array(
       'dateTime' => '2018-04-05T15:00:00+1:00',
       'timeZone' => 'Europe/Amsterdam',
   )
));

$event = $cal->events->insert($room_calendar_id, $event);
```

When I execute this code the result is an event that runs from 13:00 till 16:00 hrs. When I use these parameters via the Google calendar API try-out function it gives the same result. But in the latter case it comes back with following JSON response:

```
"start": {
  "dateTime": "2018-04-20T13:00:00+02:00",
  "timeZone": "Europe/Amsterdam"
 },
"end": {
  "dateTime": "2018-04-20T16:00:00+02:00",
  "timeZone": "Europe/Amsterdam"
  }
```

So weird it shows an offset of +02:00.
I would expect the API does not change the time and offset parameters.

When I do the same for 2018-03-20 it works fine, so daylight saving should cause this issue in my opinion.

Can someone give more information on how I should add an event without considering the daylight saving influence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timezones - such as `Europe/Amsterdam` - have Daylight Saving effects, and you can't help avoiding them, because DST is part of the things controled by timezone definitions.

And during DST, the [offset used in Amsterdam is changed from +01:00 to +02:00](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/netherlands/amsterdam). So this is not weird, it's actually the expected behaviour.

What google API is doing - probably - is adjusting an invalid offset (`2018-04-05T12:00:00+01:00`) to a valid one (`2018-04-05T13:00:00+02:00`) - btw, both correspond to the same UTC instant, so the conversion is fine.

This doesn't happen in March 20th because DST haven't started yet - in 2018, it starts on March 25th.

If you're dealing with timezones, there's no way to ignore DST effects, because [DST is part of the timezone definition](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones.html#daylight).

Comment: The thing I really did wrong is the combination of the offset AND the timezone. When I removed the offset, the result was okay!!